# I am getting 'The repository focal-security Release' no longer has a Release file for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

Today I am getting this error on my system. When I was working on my system a red notification came up on the top bar and I tried to see where it went wrong.

In terminal I tried to use below command:

```bsh
sudo apt update
```

And after that it produced this error:

```bsh
❯ sudo apt update
Alias: _ apt update
[sudo] password for user: 
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                     
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release                                                                                       
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
...                             
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                        
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix this security issue?

Comment: "No Release File" is a symptom. The real problem is above that: "*Network is unreachable*" Reconnect to your network and try again.